# We have "on Monday" for 1 occasion & "on Mondays" for repeated events, can we have similar patterns for "in July" or "in Winter"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-time),

> with a singular day of the week to refer to **one occasion**:
>
> *I’ve got to go to London on Friday.*
>
> with a plural day of the week to refer to **repeated events**:
>
> *The office is closed on Fridays.* (every Friday) In informal
>   situations, we often leave out on before plural days:
>
> Do you work Saturdays?

*I’ve got to go to London on Friday.*=*I’ve got to go to London this/next Friday.*

*The office is closed on Fridays.*=*The office is closed every Friday.*

However, I would think that "**in July**" or "**in Winter**" can be used for both cases "**one occasion**" & "**repeated events**", but I am not so sure.

Example 1:

- *I’ve got to go to London in July.*=*I’ve got to go to London this July.*
- *The office is closed in July.*=*The office is closed every July.*

Example 2:

- *I’ve got to go to London in Winter.*=*I’ve got to go to London this Winter.*
- *The office is closed in Winter.*=*The office is closed every Winter.*

We have "**on Monday**" for **1 occasion** & "**on Mondays**" for **repeated events**, can we have similar patterns for "**in July**" or "**in Winter**"?

For example, can we say the following?

- *The office is closed in Winters / in Julies.*=*The office is closed every Winter / every July.*

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/37738/50044

Comment: A quick Google search of, for example, *Januaries*, shows that such a usage exists. For example, "Average returns for various investments in Januaries vs. other months, 1970-2009. Sources: Bloomberg." I would offer a bounty to draw more attention to this question, but these days it seems bounties don't do much. Anyway you can Google the various pluralized months and seasons and make your own discoveries. One thing for sure there is no "rule", as @WS2 purports.

Comment: Another Google example: "In Januaries past, the McGillivray's, too, had taken delight in the once yearly reprieve from tending to guest."

Comment: These uses might not be exactly the same as what the OP is asking about, but the question deserves more attention. As does  the use of "we're closed summers", noted by @fixer1234,who has classified it as odd. Nevertheless it's not ungrammatical, and ***closed summers***, et al . are used with great frequency in travel guides, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules work rather differently for months and seasons.

**Months.**

*The golf course is closed in/during January* could mean every January or just the next forthcoming January. To be absolutely clear one would need to say either *...is closed every January/is always closed in/during January*; or *...is closed this/next January*.

**Seasons**

*The golf course is closed in/during winter* means *every winter*. *The golf course is closed this/next winter* - means only this year.

Comment: Can you refer a reference source  for your answer?

Comment: I think you need to edit your answer a bit because simple present tense can only be used to say repeated things. So, say "*it will be closed this/next January*" or "*it is being closed this/next January*"

Comment: @Tom Seven decades as a native speaker is the only reference I can offer, I'm afraid. I believe the preposition is independent of tense.

Comment: I've seen usage like "we're closed summers", although it seems odd.  One problem with months is that so many end in "y".  Is there even a rule for pluralizing them (Januaries)?

Comment: @fixer1234 I think *We're closed summers* is possibly American. One seldom sees it expressed that way in Britain. And I have never seen *We are closed Januaries*. Personally I would say *We are closed in/during January (every year)*; or *We are closed in/during winter*. The last would mean all winters. If you wanted to restrict the meaning to the current winter only, it would be necessary to say *We are closed this winter*, or *We are closed for the winter*.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I researched pluralization of month names.  It turns out there really is such a thing (it's covered for each month name on wiktionary).  BTW, months ending in "y" are optionally "ies" or "ys".  I don't recall ever seeing the plurals in use.  So it sounds like there might not be a rule precluding treatment similar to weekday names, but it would likely seem odd.  I think your answer captures general practice.

Comment: @fixer1234 Umm. I've never seen the months pluralised. I think it is something I would be inclined to avoid.

Comment: This answer is disturbing in its lack of effort to substantiate its claims,  especially in response to proffered counter examples.

Comment: @fixer1234 on this site "rule" is shorthand for  "general practice", just as "grammatical"  is shorthand for "acceptable". Meanwhile, *closed summers* is  idiomatic exactly in the places we would expect it might be, in travel books and guide books for example.

Comment: @Clare, I understand that "usage makes the rules" in English.  Something becomes common practice and when that practice becomes sufficiently widespread and appears to be longer lived than a passing fad, it gets documented in the language reference materials.  That documentation includes figuring out the details of the usage so it can be described as a "rule".  Once the rule has been documented, that usage might become less common or morph, but the documentation is cumulative, the rules aren't removed from the references if that usage changes.  (cont'd)

Comment: So there are several cases where the documented "rules" differ from common usage: documented usage that's no longer common, and at least limited common usage that might not yet be formally documented (either prior to a new usage being documented or a morphed usage not yet updated in the documentation).  What's the right terminology to distinguish between the documented rules and common practice that is different?